# Checking received faxes after a certain date

Tags: java, calendar, println

So this an old code that is supposed to check for received faxes but for some reason I could not find the error.

```
 Calendar receivedAfter = Calendar.getInstance();
 receivedAfter.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -14);

 System.out.println();
 System.out.println("Checking for received faxes since : " + receivedAfter);
```

My output is

Checking for received faxes since :

```
java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1386017803339,areFieldsSet=true,areAllFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="America/New_York",offset=-18000000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,transitions=235,lastRule=java.util.SimpleTimeZone[id=America/New_York,offset=-18000000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,startYear=0,startMode=3,startMonth=2,startDay=8,startDayOfWeek=1,startTime=7200000,startTimeMode=0,endMode=3,endMonth=10,endDay=1,endDayOfWeek=1,endTime=7200000,endTimeMode=0]],firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=1,YEAR=2013,MONTH=11,WEEK_OF_YEAR=49,WEEK_OF_MONTH=1,DAY_OF_MONTH=2,DAY_OF_YEAR=336,DAY_OF_WEEK=2,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=1,AM_PM=1,HOUR=3,HOUR_OF_DAY=15,MINUTE=56,SECOND=43,MILLISECOND=339,ZONE_OFFSET=-18000000,DST_OFFSET=0]
```

Why is it printing out all this data??? 
Any suggestions why ?

Comment: You should mark the right answer (syntaxerror's one) as the "accepted" answer, instead of just saying "it works".

Answer (score 1):

It is the default implementation of the `toString()` method inside `GregorianCalendar`.

A quick alternative, without doing a lot of date formatting, would be:

```
 System.out.println("Checking for received faxes since : " + receivedAfter.getTime());
```

This gives you a java.util.Date object which has a more human-friendly `toString()`method.

Answer (score 0):

That is the entire object.  You probably want a specific field from within the object.  Try

```
 System.out.println("Checking for received faxes since : " + receivedAFter.YEAR() + '/' +  receivedAfter.MONTH() + '/' + receivedAfter.DAY_OF_MONTH());
```

Comment: Not "the entire object". The result of that object `toString()` invocation.